# detecting quota limits reCAPTCHA android

Tags: android, recaptcha

I'm wondering if there any callbacks reCAPTCHA for android (https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha) when limit for requests exceeds quota?
Also, how exactly is the limit calculated? Does it count every call to `SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(YOUR_API_SITE_KEY)`? Or does it count only those calls which resulted to challenge displaying?